# React Redux Component passing props not re-render

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm using React with react-redux package and I've created a Redux component.

```
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

class Prova extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = { ...props }
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        if (prevProps.errors !== this.props.errors) {
            this.setState({
                errors: this.props.errors
            });
        }
    }

    render() {

        const props = this.props.errors ? <div>props: {Object.keys(this.props.errors).map(prop => <div className='props'>{prop}</div>)}</div> : <>NO ERRORS</>

        return (
            <div>
                {props}
            </div>
        )

    }
}

function mapState(state, ownProps) {
    return {
    }
}

const actionCreators = {
}

const connectedProva = connect(mapState, actionCreators)(Prova)
export { connectedProva as Prova }
```

I'm calling this component like this:

```
<Prova errors={this.state.errors} />
```

Where errors is stored and updated in the state of the Parent component.

The problem is that errors aren't updated in the store state of redux but in the state of the component and this value is passed to the Prova component as "simple" props. But updating the Parent state doesn't re-render the Prova component.

Is it possible that using a Redux component hide the props passed? they are readed only when the Prova component is created the first time.

Thanks

**EDIT:**

Finally I understood the problem.
In the parent component where I was updating the errors state I wasn't destroying the prev version of errors but filling with the new data.
Now it's working changing it to:

```
var errors = { ...prevErrors }
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you show your parent component?

Comment: you should learn how the redux works because u dont have an action creator for the current action. u just treat it as normal component that is just connected to redux

Comment: I know how redux works, but the props that I'm passing to the child component doesn't come from the store state but from the state of the parent component, so in this case redux isn't used.

Comment: The parent component is a simple Component which update his state and pass it to the child component as props